# How DBMS compares primary keys?

Tags: database

I want protect my data at database level. Then, the solution I thought was: have a composite primary key with 4 column index, among them 3 is also foreign keys.

> name, id_discipline, name_step, year_step

But I'm from Brazil and in our words we have accents, so I'm confusing about the comparison between the new data to be inserted in database and the data already inserted. One example:

If I insert `'Mat' - '1' - '1st' - '2012'`, at database level, my data are protect because these columns are primary keys, then I can't insert another equal entry. `('Mat' - '1' - '1st' - '2012')`

The question is, among them, **name** and **name_step** can have accents. How DBMS will work with the comparison? Will I have trouble with accents and comparison?

Must I use ISO-8859-1 as my charset and store without `htmlentities()` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

- First: looks like you're a bit confused regarding the terminology. There's at most 1 **primary key** per table (that's where the 'primary' comes from, after all). There may be more keys or indexed columns (that's those foreign keys - they're keys of some other table, but regarding this table, they're just indexed fields with a constraint).
- Whether you can store strings with accents depends on the **datatype**. For storing national strings, the NVARCHAR data type is used, how the non-ascii characters are handled  and stored depends on the **character set** used - this varies with the DBMS used. As other data types, NVARCHARs can be compared.
- For comparison of NVARCHAR strings **collation** comes to scene. This says how to say what strings are 'lesser/greater' then another strings. Again, details vary with DBMS. Collation doesn't matter much when talking indexes (there, you're only interested in whether the strings equal or not), it becomes important when you're ordering.
- It is a good practice to have **numeric id's as primary keys**. You can have indexes for your string data for quick queries and at the same time data manipulation is easier when you can specify records using the numeric id.

EDIT:
So, to the question and your comment:

If you make sure that you input your data as the DB expects, the comparison will work. That means, in your code, the data must be in the character set defined for the table/column (or the default for the database, if you didn't specify any). Usually, the easiest way would be to use `NVARCHAR` as the datatype for fields which contain national language strings and input unicode strings at the side of code.

Technically, it's possible to use VARCHAR to store natinal character strings, but it's easier to get it wrong - you must make sure that you keep the same character set settings everywhere: the table definition, database connection, code. And you may easily get into dead ends, when you suddenly need to input accented characters not contained in your chosen character set, so I'd strongly recommend using NVARCHAR and unicode.

Comment: The case is: I want protect my data at database level. Then, the solution I thought was: have a composite primary key with 4 column index,  among them 3 is also foreign keys.
Ok.
If I insert 'Mat' - '1' - '1st' - '2012', at database level, my data are protect because these columns are primary keys, then I can't insert another entry equal. ('Mat' - '1' - '1st' - '2012').
So returning my main question, in my country we have accents in words, how DBMS will compare the entries to guarantee that entry is unique? Will I have trouble with accents and comparison?

Comment: Oh, I've misunderstood that. Still, I'd recommend to have a numeric id and a unique index for those columns. Manipulating records with this kind of private key tends to be awkward.
To the rest - I'll update the answer a bit, but I (or others) can only be more specific if you say what DB you're using and what's the definition of the table (including charset)

Comment: About the keys, the problem was solved, I'm using one primary key with auto increment. And  I'm using a bit of unique keys.
I'll use MySQL as my DBMS.